# pandas apply lambda if else incorrect

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, lambda

dataframe with data in this format

```
dfs = pd.read_csv('try.tsv', sep='\t')
dfs.head()
guide freq
g1   text1
g2   text1,text2,text1
g3   text1,text2,text3
g4   text1
g5   text1,text2,text3,text4,text5
g6   NaN
g7   text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6
```

fill NaN

```
dfs['freq'].fillna('no_guide', inplace=True)

dfs
    guide   freq
0   g1  text1
1   g2  text1,text2
2   g3  text1,text2,text3
3   g4  text1
4   g5  text1,text2,text3,text4,text5
5   g6  no_guide
6   g7  text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6
```

I need to count the number of times text appears in each row i tried this

```
dfs['counts'] = dfs['freq'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x : '0' if x == 'no_guide' else len(set(x)))
```

what i expect to see (after dropping freq col)

```
guide counts
g1   1
g2   2
g3   3
g4   1
g5   5
g6   0
g5   6
```

what i rather see

```
guide counts
g1   1
g2   2
g3   3
g4   1
g5   5
g6   1 #this should be g6 0
g5   6
```

Am i missing something in my lambda clause or there is a different way to do it?

Comment: You first replace the `NaN` values and then call `.str.split()`, so you really want the condition to be `0 if x == ['no_guide']` to get your desired output.

Comment: let me try that

Comment: it worked mind posting it as an anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was that you were first filling the `NaN` and then using `.str.split()`, so the equality should be with a list, not the element of the list. You can see this by first checking what `x` is in your `lambda` function.

```
dfs['freq'].str.split(',')
#0                                       [text1]
#1                         [text1, text2, text1]
#2                         [text1, text2, text3]
#3                                       [text1]
#4           [text1, text2, text3, text4, text5]
#5                                    [no_guide]
#6    [text1, text2, text3, text4, text5, text6]
```

The correct equality to check is whether x is a list whose only element is 'no_guide':

```
lambda x: 0 if x == ['no_guide'] else len(set(x))
```

Since `len(set(x))` returns a number, you may also want to return 0 and not the string '0'.

Comment: this works, sorry i forgot to mention another thing i have edited the question i use set because in some cases for example this `g2   text1,text2,text1` text1 can appear twice but i will just count it once

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that. Let me get to that.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
df['freq'].fillna('no_guide', inplace=True)
df['counts'] = df['freq'].str.split(',', expand=True)\
                         .apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('text')).sum(1)

df
```

Output:

```
  guide                                 freq  counts
0    g1                                text1     1.0
1    g2                    text1,text2,text1     3.0
2    g3                    text1,text2,text3     3.0
3    g4                                text1     1.0
4    g5        text1,text2,text3,text4,text5     5.0
5    g6                             no_guide     0.0
6    g7  text1,text2,text3,text4,text5,text6     6.0
```